# Nitrous.io for Mac does not sync .git?

Tags: nitrousio

I am trying out [Nitrous.io](http://nitrous.io) -- it is a very nice tool.  I am also using Nitrous' Mac application which syncs box content to a local directory -- except I have noticed that it doesn't sync the `.git` directory.  I assume this is intentional(?).  Is there a list someplace that describes what is and what is not synced?

Comment: It appears Nitrous uses [Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) for synching, but I haven't found a config file for it on my box.

Comment: That's good information.  How did you determine that Unison is used?

Comment: I have a `.unison` directory on my box.  I may try to work with its configuration per http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html

Comment: Yeah, I found out by discovering that .unison folder. It hadn't occurred to me that I could put a config in there; I just noticed there wasn't one already. Keep us posted!

Answer (score 3):

You can update the file `<home dir>\Nitrous\<box name>\.unison\default.prf` and add any configuration there per the manual: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html

Mine contains this line, for example:

```
    ignore=Name node_modules
```

This way my `node_modules` folder is not synced in either direction.

You could add this line to yours:

```
    ignorenot=Name .git
```

As @ajhit406 noted though, you should handle your git actions in one place (the box, in this case).

Answer (score 2):

The `.git` directory is not synced on purpose.  You should be SSH'ing into your box to manage your git repositories.

In the Mac application shortcut menu, hover over the box you want to SSH into, and click "Open Shell".  You should enter any git commands from your box in the cloud.

Comment: I understand all this.  But is there anything else that isn't synced by the Mac client?

Comment: The Nitrous Mac app will exclude .git files and will only sync files within the ~/workspace folder.

Answer (score 0):

Nitrous has a resource about this: http://help.nitrous.io/nitrous-desktop/

In the document it details that these are the files and directories that aren't synced:

`.unison
.git
.svn
.hg
CVS
.DS_Store
.AppleDouble
.LSOverride
.Spotlight-V100
.Trashes
*.sock
*.sw?
._* , *~`